# DNS redirect not working for some site visitors

Tags: redirects, dns, 1and1

I have a site hosted with VidaHost (www.thinkchecksubmit.org) on a webspace-only package, and a number of domain names registered with 1and1. The site is built on a Wordpress install with a custom theme, and we have a DNS redirect from the primary URL to the IP of our webspace at VidaHost.

For the majority of visitors, heading to thinkchecksubmit.org results in the site loading fine. However I've had reports that some visitors are greeted with 1and1's /defaultsite page (shown below), rather than being redirected to the Vidahost webspace.

[image: Infuriating error message]

The DNS redirect appears to be correctly configured; running thinkchecksubmit.org through the OpenDNS checker (https://cachecheck.opendns.com) shows that the redirect is working as expected.

1and1 have repeatedly told me it's not their problem and that the affected visitors must be loading a cached version of the page from before any content was uploaded (this odds of this being true for multiple people all over the world are vanishingly small), or that the issue is with VisaHost's server being incorrectly configured.

VidaHost have assured me that the site's configured correctly at their end, and that their server's experienced no downtime at the time these errors have been experienced - so it must be something at 1and1's end. You can see where this is going.

So basically, neither party's been able to offer an explanation why it's occurring (nor why it works for most people who visit the site, but not others) - given that the error page is 1and1's default holding page, I'm inclined to think that the problem is at their end. Unfortunately, because we have a domain-only package with 1and1, I can't access the "defaultsite" page to try and modify things there for the few people who aren't redirected automatically.

I'm tearing my hair out over this, as I've not found any way to resolve it and I need to be confident that anyone demonstrating the site at an event won't have the holding page above splashed across a 20ft screen in front of thousands of people.

Can anyone out there recommend steps I could take to resolve the issue?

Comment: These options from web hosts and registrars often fail periodically it seems. We get these kinds of questions here fairly often. The best thing to do is actually create a web space for the domain/sub-domain and create a redirect there based upon what web server you are using.